# Loading a JNI library in scala

Tags: scala, java-native-interface

I am trying to load a JNI library that is needed by a third-party library that I am using.  Since the library only needs to be loaded once, I tried to put the loading in the companion class.  I thought this would work:

```
import com.example.Solver

object MyClass {
  System.loadLibrary("jnilibrary")
}

class MyClass {
  import MyClass._
  implicit val solver = new Solver()
}
```

This throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` in the Solver class initializer (`Solver.<clinit>`), apparently because the JNI library is not yet loaded.

Changing the class to

```
class MyClass {
  System.loadLibrary("jnilibrary")
  implicit val solver = new Solver()
}
```

works, so I do have the library in the correct place.  Moving the `System.loadLibrary` to after the `solver` declaration causes it to fail the same way as when I try to load the library in the companion class.

I theorized that it was trying to resolve the types before running the initializers, so I tried moving the library loading to a base class.  I hoped that would mean base class (which loads the library) was fully initialized before the derived class (which loads the class) started to initialize.

```
object Base {
  System.loadLibrary("jnilibrary")
}

class Base {
  import Base._
}

class MyClass extends Base {
  implicit val solver = new Solver()
}
```

This also fails.

I can obviously load the library in the class, but that is redundant.  It probably does not slow things down much (assuming that loadLibrary will not reload an already loaded library) but is less clean than I would like.

Is there a way to get this to work with the companion object?

Comment: I guess you missed the eye-opening discussion of this topic circa 2011: http://www.scala-archive.org/Static-initialiser-equivalent-is-there-a-better-way-td3232700.html

Comment: Yes I did.  I think I searched for loadLibrary specifically, rather than static in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex Cohn pointed out, the solution is

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass
  implicit val solver = new Solver()
}
```